# Scala maps groupBy using proper naming instead of _._1 in tuples

Tags: scala, maps

Scala map contains key as tuple. How will I be able to group based on an element in tuple without using _._1 since usage of _1 is less readable.

Example:

```
val m = Map((1,true,"case0") -> List(1,2), (2,false,"case0") -> List(3,4), 
(1,true,"case1") -> List(2,4))
```

Here if I have to group by key.*1, we can do it using groupBy(*._1._1). Can we do the same operation using case statement and avoid using _1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
m.groupBy{case (key, _) => key._1}
```

and taking this one step further

```
m.groupBy{case ((key, _,_), _) => key}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. m.groupBy{case ((key, _,_), _) => key}
will solve my exact purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Create a case class for keys

```
case class Key(id: Int, flag:Boolean, name:String)

val m = Map(Key(1,true,"case0") -> List(1,2), 
            Key(2,false,"case0") -> List(3,4), 
            Key(1,true,"case1") -> List(2,4))

m.groupBy(_._1.id)
```